# Not able to parse Json String to get the key value using JSON

Tags: java

I have a json response string like this

```
string result ={"username": "sdrG", "size": 965204,  "filename": "test.doc"}
```

From this am trying to get the size value

for that am using JSON object to convert JSON string get the key values

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(result); // json
String size = (String) jObject.get("size");
System.out.println(size);
```

But his code is not working for me getting

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["size"] not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little modification, your code worked for me:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    String result ="{\"username\": \"sdrG\", \"size\": 965204,  \"filename\": \"test.doc\"}";
     JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(result); // json
        String size = String.valueOf((Integer) jObject.get("size"));
        System.out.println(size);
}
```

Used  :-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

In case your Json is stored in StringBuffer, you can do:-

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
 JSONObject jObject  = (JSONObject)parser.parse(result);
 String size = (String) jObject.get("size");
 System.out.println(size);
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the type of parameter, rather than parsing. `JSONObject(String)` is a valid constructor.

Comment: @KDM
what is the type of parameter you guessed? If parameter was wrong, he would have got compilation issue. Right? And this was just another way to validate the work.

Comment: The `jObject.get("size")` is an Integer, not a String. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @KDM 
I saw that, so why was there no ClassCastexception instead?

Comment: It does generate a `ClassCastException` in a test program.  I guess the OP is catching the exception and regenerating the message in his code.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["size"] not found is the exception thrown. So that suggest that you did not make a logical guess there. Nevertheless.